# https --> http lightweight proxy

Tags: linux, redhat, proxy, https, http

I'm new to web servers and need some advice.

I've wrote simple HTTP server based on [served](https://github.com/meltwater/served) over `RedHat 7.2`.

Sadly, `served` as far as I understand does not support HTTPS.

In order to keep in line with company guidelines I want to setup `HTTPS --> HTTP`.

I tried to configure `tinyproxy` following [this guide](https://medium.com/@isabelcmdcosta/how-i-set-up-tinyproxy-as-a-forward-proxy-and-reverse-proxy-2a5dc1ed64e4), but it does not seem to fit as HTTPS to HTTP proxy.

How to configure tinyProxy to receive HTTPS and output HTTP?
Could you please point me to resources about this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/):

> Stunnel is a proxy designed to add TLS encryption functionality to
> existing clients and servers without any changes in the programs'
> code.

Answer (score 3):

I'd personally look at Hitch - rather than running a full fat webserver (Apache) Hitch is purpose-built to terminate TLS connections.

It's built by the Varnish team and has an excellent security track record, along with being async IO driven so it is much leaner/faster than Apache2's process per connection model.

https://hitch-tls.org/

Answer (score 1):

As I understood this, you want `tinyproxy` to terminate TLS and speak plain HTTP to the backend.

It [seems](https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy/issues/88) that this is unsupported by tinyproxy:

> No, tinyproxy does not support transparent HTTPS proxying. Only transparent HTTP proxy. Rerouting port 443 to port 80 will not work; those are two very different protocols. The only way is to manually set up proxy in the system/environment, or in the browser.
>
> If HTTPS transparent proxying is a must, consider using Squid.

But you can use Apache (packages `httpd` and `mod_ssl`) to do this:

*Note*: I'm assuming that your backend server binds to port 8080 (as it makes things easier with SELinux). For details see [semanage port](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/semanage-port.8.html), [httpd_selinux](https://linux.die.net/man/8/httpd_selinux).

- Set up Apache to use TLS (see e.g. [Digicert](https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/apache-openssl.htm#ssl_certificate_install)'s guide, plus [security recommendations](https://cipherli.st))
- You should end up with something like this:

  `<VirtualHost *:443>
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html
      ServerName www.yourdomain.com
      SSLEngine on
      SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your_domain_name.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your_private.key
      SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/chain.crt
  </VirtualHost>`
- Add the directives for proxying: 
  `[...]
  SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/chain.crt
  ProxyEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine on
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  <Proxy http://localhost:8080/>
    Require all granted
  </Proxy>`
- Set up SELinux: `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_relay=1`
- Restart `httpd`: `systemctl restart httpd`

Comment: I think that the OP was not asking about a transparent proxy, but how to put a "HTTPS tunnel" in front of a HTTP server. A transparent proxy is "a server that intercepts the connection between an end-user or device and the Internet"